# How to set LayoutManager for RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager

In my application I want show some `RecyclerViews`.
I want **show 3 item in one row**, I my application should use **4** `recyclerView` because each `recyclerVews` each data other **API**.

In one of `RecyclerView` I can show 3 Item in one row, and I should show another 3 `recyclerViews` above of this `RecyclerView`.

Please see this image to understand my mean : 
[image]

**I write below code in Java :**

```
if (movieResponse.getData().getStars().size() > 0) {
                            starsModel.clear();
                            starsModel.addAll(movieResponse.getData().getStars());
                            castAdapter = new CastAdapter(context, starsModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView.setAdapter(castAdapter);
                        } else {
                            goneView(infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView);
                        }
                        //Get Directors
                        if (movieResponse.getData().getDirectors().size() > 0) {
                            directorsModel.clear();
                            directorsModel.add(movieResponse.getData().getDirectors().get(0));
                            directorAdapter = new DirectorAdapter(context, directorsModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 1));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setAdapter(directorAdapter);
                        } else {
                            goneView(infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView);
                        }
                        //Get Writers
                        if (movieResponse.getData().getWriters().size() > 0) {
                            writersModel.clear();
                            writersModel.add(movieResponse.getData().getWriters().get(0));
                            writerAdapter = new WriterAdapter(context, writersModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 1));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView.setAdapter(writerAdapter);
                        } else {
                            invisibleView(infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView);
                        }
                        //Get Writers2
                        if (movieResponse.getData().getWriters().size() > 0) {
                            writersModel.clear();
                            writersModel.add(movieResponse.getData().getWriters().get(0));
                            writerAdapter = new WriterAdapter(context, writersModel);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 1));
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2.setAdapter(writerAdapter);
                        }
```

**My XML code:**

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastLay"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastLay"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastLay"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_CastRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/infoEpisodeFrag_WriterRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5" />
```

How to show 3 up `recyclerview's` items **align** by under `recyclerView`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Horizontal` `RecyclerView` instead of `Grid` and pass only 3 items with using `starsModel.subList(0,3);`

```
castAdapter = new CastAdapter(context, starsModel.subList(0,3));
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
infoEpisodeFrag_DirectorRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: I want show Director and Write recycperView such as Cast recyclerView. use you code?

Comment: what you mean ? i didn't understand you

Comment: For Director and Writer I initialize another RecyclerView. I want show this RecyclerView align by Cast RecyclerView

Comment: can you send to me your skype ID?

Comment: you can find my fb account at my profil, it's better to talk here so others can help and find sollution for their problem